# telepresence: error: workload "xxx-service.default" not found

Tags: minikube, telepresence

I have this chart of a personal project deployed in `minikube`:

```
---
# Source: frontend/templates/service.yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
    name: xxx-app-service
spec:
    selector:
        app: xxx-app
    ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 3000
          targetPort: 3000
---
# Source: frontend/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    annotations:
        deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: '3'
    creationTimestamp: '2022-06-19T21:57:01Z'
    generation: 3
    labels:
        app: xxx-app
    name: xxx-app
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: '43299'
    uid: 7c43767a-abbd-4806-a9d2-6712847a0aad
spec:
    progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
    replicas: 1
    revisionHistoryLimit: 10
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: xxx-app
    strategy:
        rollingUpdate:
            maxSurge: 25%
            maxUnavailable: 25%
        type: RollingUpdate
    template:
        metadata:
            creationTimestamp: null
            labels:
                app: xxx-app
        spec:
            containers:
                - image: "registry.gitlab.com/esavara/xxx/wm:staging"
                  name: frontend
                  imagePullPolicy: Always
                  terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
                  terminationMessagePolicy: File
                  ports:
                      - containerPort: 3000
                  livenessProbe:
                      httpGet:
                          path: /
                          port: 3000
                      initialDelaySeconds: 10
                      periodSeconds: 3
                  env:
                      - name: PORT
                        value: "3000"
                  resources: {}
            dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
            imagePullSecrets:
                - name: regcred
            restartPolicy: Always
            schedulerName: default-scheduler
            securityContext: {}
            terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
---
# Source: frontend/templates/ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    creationTimestamp: '2022-06-19T22:28:58Z'
    generation: 1
    name: xxx-app
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: '44613'
    uid: b58dcd17-ee1f-42e5-9dc7-d915a21f97b5
spec:
    ingressClassName: nginx
    rules:
        - http:
              paths:
                  - backend:
                        service:
                            name: "xxx-app-service"
                            port:
                                number: 3000
                    path: /
                    pathType: Prefix
status:
    loadBalancer:
        ingress:
            - ip: 192.168.39.80
---
# Source: frontend/templates/gitlab-registry-sealed.json
{
    "kind": "SealedSecret",
    "apiVersion": "bitnami.com/v1alpha1",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "regcred",
        "namespace": "default",
        "creationTimestamp": null
    },
    "spec": {
        "template": {
            "metadata": {
                "name": "regcred",
                "namespace": "default",
                "creationTimestamp": null
            },
            "type": "kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson",
            "data": null
        },
        "encryptedData": {
            ".dockerconfigjson": "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"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use Telepresence to redirect the traffic from the deployed application to a Docker container which have my project mounted inside and has hot-reloading, to continue the development of it but inside Kubernetes, but running `telepresence intercept xxx-app-service --port 3000:3000 --env-file /tmp/xxx-app-service.env` fails with the following error:

```
telepresence: error: workload "xxx-app-service.default" not found
```

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?